# Linux samba server: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -12

Tags: mount, pam, server-message-block, cifs, smb-conf

Server: RHEL 5.9 / smbd 3.0.33
- Clients: various, though all were using current mount.cifs (5.2)

I already solved this problem, but it was such a nightmare to hunt down these error codes I felt like it needed universal documenting.

**Symptoms**: Unpredictable, intermittent mount failure from one specific cifs client to linux samba server. All my linux clients pam_mount user homes at login. Randomly, and sporadically the home dir mounts began to fail on **one** machine. Logins and mounts continued to work flawlessly on all other clients. Initially I thought an unusual amount of activity on the broken client was causing smbd to freak, but intermittent failures lingered even after usage died down.

Attempting to mount by hand fails and reports:

```
Errors from underlying mount program
mount error(12): Cannot allocate memory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Set `<debug enable="1"/>` in /etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml to get more info from pam_mount:

```
command: 'mount' '-t' 'cifs' '//my_server/watdo' '/home/watdo' '-o' 'user=watdo,uid=666,gid=666'
pam_mount(misc.c:38): set_myuid<pre>: (ruid/rgid=0/0, e=0/0)
pam_mount(misc.c:38): set_myuid<post>: (ruid/rgid=0/0, e=0/0)
pam_mount(mount.c:64): Errors from underlying mount program:
pam_mount(mount.c:68): mount error(12): Cannot allocate memory
pam_mount(mount.c:68): Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`
```

/var/log/kern.log also reported on this event:

```
kernel: [4316790.256149] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -12
```

'echo 1 > /proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI' **cranks** up mount.cifs debug (writes to /var/log/debug). Here's the good part (look familiar?):

```
CIFS Session Established successfully
For smb_command 117
Sending smb:  total_len 88
cifs_sync_mid_result: cmd=117 mid=54307 state=4
Mapping smb error code 0xc0000205 to POSIX err -12
```

At this point there is literally no other information available on the client side. cifs mount request goes out and the client dies almost immediately. mount.cifs error(12) is pretty uninformative (man page doesn't help, thx guys). Extensive internet searching reveals this is a common error code, also confirms it as uninformative.

Time to check on the server! Set `log level = 3` for smbd in /etc/samba/smb.conf (from the Using Samba book: "Levels above 3 are for use by the developers and dump enormous amounts of cryptic information." lol!). Here's the relevant line:

`[2013/02/08 10:18:03, 3] smbd/error.c:error_packet_set(106)
  error packet at smbd/reply.c(514) cmd=117 (SMBtconX) NT_STATUS_INSUFF_SERVER_RESOURCES`

Almost there... from [smb mailing list archive](http://fixunix.com/samba/363500-%5Bsamba%5D-problem-nt_status_insuff_server_resources.html) I found someone reporting a sort of similar issue, identified as a pegged share limit on an individual smb connection. List open shares on the server:

`smbstatus -S | grep <serverIP> | wc -l` returned **2048**. Very conspicuous.

Actually examining the output of `smbstatus -S` revealed *thousands* of entries for 'IPC$'. [Samba docs on IPC$](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/securing-samba.html#id2618877) reveal it is involved with anonymous share browsing and access to "some other resources". I set host deny on the server in /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[IPC$]
hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
```

Works great now. OK, hopefully something here helps some poor soul some time in the future.

I guess in the spirit of the site I will ask a question: Why would smbd not clean up IPC$ shares? Why establish one IPC$ per user connection to a share rather than one per client connection? Can you disable IPC$ share creation from the client side? Is there a way to increase the max # connections per share (not that this would have helped in this case)? I didn't see it in the docs.

Comment: "Randomly, and sporadically", "intermittent failures" and memory allocation errors - did you [check](http://www.memtest.org/) for (physical) memory errors?

Comment: The IPC$ share is always accessed in a per-user context because it's really (in the MSFT world) a remote-procedure-call (RPC) interface.  That is, the IPC$ share gives a user a channel to authenticate to the Server service such that they can then make RPC calls to it.  It's good security practice to disable it if you have no need for it (and tbh I have a hard time believing that anyone does).

Comment: Thanks for detailed example of samba troubleshooting. Abstract error messages is nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

This is an oldie, but considering it's unanswered and I was looking into IPC$ and Samba, I will give it a try for the sake of documentation.

> Why would smbd not clean up IPC$ shares?

As stated above in the comments to your question, the service is used for remote administration and communication among servers, and particularly in Samba it's used for some browsing and tcp/ip purposes. Unless you need it for some reason or something doesn't work, it's safe to disable it. [1]

> Why establish one IPC$ per user connection to a share rather than one
>   per client connection?

Because a user can have multiple client connections.

> Can you disable IPC$ share creation from the client side?

Yes and no. It doesn't really disable the creation of the IPC$ share, but you can disable access to it from the windows client.[2]

For windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 10, you can do the following registry edit:

1. Click Start, type “regedit” in the Search box, and then click regedit.exe in the search results. The User Account Control dialog box appears.
2. Say “Yes” to the UAC prompt and the Registry Editor should open.
3. Open the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE branch.
4. Open the SYSTEM branch.
5. Open the CurrentControlSet branch.
6. Open the Services branch.
7. Open the LanmanServer branch.
8. Select the Parameters branch.
9. Select Edit, New, “DWORD (32-bit) Value”
10. Type “AutoShareWks” and press Enter. (Leave the default value of 0.)
11. Reboot or restart the service using a Command Prompt (DOS or terminal): “net stop server” then “net start server”.

> Is there a way to increase the max # connections per share (not that
>   this would have helped in this case)? I didn't see it in the docs.

Yes[3]. Below the share just input:

```
[share]
   max connections = ##
```

Where XX is the number of connections.

Sources:

- [1] https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/old/Samba3-HOWTO/securing-samba.html
- [2] https://www.petri.com/disable_administrative_shares
- [2] https://www.weavweb.net/2015/08/27/disabling-hidden-shares-in-windows-10-windows-vista-windows-7-and-windows-8-1/
- [2] https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/954422/how-to-remove-administrative-shares-in-windows-server-2008
- [3] https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html